# Stationarity in a ARIMA Model with External Regressors

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, arima, stationarity

I have a question about when we apply an ARIMA model with external regressors. Just a quick note of my understanding on the topic, an ARIMA model with external regressors is when we apply a Regression model between $y_t$ and $(x_{1,t},x_{2,t}....x_{k,t})$, and then, because the errors of this model might be further autocorrelated, we can apply an ARIMA model to the error terms.

-> The doubt I have is with respect to the information available in this link.

In it, the author says the following:

> "An important consideration when estimating a regression with ARMA
>   errors is that all of the variables in the model must first be
>   stationary. Thus, we first have to check that $y_t$ and
>   $(x_{1,t},x_{2,t}....x_{k,t})$   appear to be stationary. If we
>   estimate the model when any of these are non-stationary, the estimated
>   coefficients will not be consistent estimates (and therefore may not
>   be meaningful)."

So according to this excerpt, the author is saying that before we apply a Regression model between $y_t$ and the set of $(x_{1,t},x_{2,t}....x_{k,t})$, and then apply an ARMA model on the errors of this regression, we must first ensure that the $x$ and $y$ variables are stationary; or else the estimated coefficients we get are not reliable. I don't understand why this has to be true. 
Because stationarity detrends a series, wouldn't it be better if we make use of the respective trends in each $x$ variable to forecast the value of the $y$ variable?

Comment: Note that if the trends are stochastic (unit-root type), this will not help in forecasting.

Comment: The statement is false, there is no such requirement. The errors must be stationary (because you've assumed they follow an ARMA process), but there is no requirement on either $y_t$ or $x_{i,t}$.

Comment: Meaning that, if I take the residuals from the regression model, if I wish to further model it, I would difference the series to make it stationary and then apply an ARMA model to it?

Comment: No. If the residuals have a unit root, then the coefficients of the regression are wrong (spurious regression). Differencing the residuals to fit a second-stage model to them won't fix that.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, are you sure there is no problem if, say, $y$ and $x$s are integrated? I guess if they are cointegrated, the point estimates of the regression equation could be fine, though I am not sure about the estimates of the standard errors. I have no good argument, just feel somehow suspicious.

Comment: @ChrisHaug How do I check if the residuals have a Unit Root?

Comment: @RichardHardy If they are all cointegrated, then the errors are stationary and the regression coefficient estimator is superconsistent (not inconsistent as mentioned above). Like I said, the requirement is on the error term only.

Comment: @ChrisHaug, I am aware of the fact that point estimates are superconsistent. I am more worried about the standard errors. Are they fine out of the box or do they need to be adjusted?

Comment: @RichardHardy I don't recall the result exactly but a priori I wouldn't expect the inference on those coefficients to be standard, no. I don't think that invalidates my original point though, does it?